# Function not defined error in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

I have a c# ASP.NET project that is being modified to work with firefox & chrome (previously, the client was IE only).

I'm am coming across one problem with firefox that I cannot solve.

Simplified code from a user control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("TOOLS", Page.ResolveUrl("~/resources/Tools.js"));

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "STARTUP_" + ClientID, "SetupGlobal();", true);
}
```

Simplified code from tools.js:

```
var ___GLOBAL_REFRESH;

function SetupGlobal()
{
    if(___GLOBAL_REFRESH == null || ___GLOBAL_REFRESH == undefined)
    {
        ___GLOBAL_REFRESH = new GLOBALRESET();
    }
}
```

In the page, the script include appears near the top and the SetupGlobal(); Appears near the bottom. In Chrome and IE it works fine but in Firefox, it says SetupGlobal is undefined.

Comment: Your sample code works perfectly in IE, Chrome and FireFox with .net version 4 .0 and 4.5.

Comment: I think something else is wrong, not the code sample you've shown. I suggest load your page in IE/Chrome & FireFox separately and compare raw html (right click on the page, select "view page source"). There may be some difference in page rendering.

Comment: Turns out you are correct. Breaking it down, I eventually found out that everything in tools.js is wrapped in this if statement: if(hideObject == undefined || hideObject == null). In IE this works fine but in firefox it throws an exception and bails out.